# Microsoft Azure Mobile Services OrderBy function

Tags: sorting, azure, sql-order-by, azure-mobile-services

How can I retrieve the last 10 records from a table using azure mobile services. I tried the following but it's syntactically wrong
App.MobileService.GetTable().OrderBy().Take(10).ToListAsync();
I know that I have to use the CreatedAt attribute, but I can't figure out how it's done

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
App.MobileService.GetTable().OrderBy('__createdAt').Take(10).ToListAsync();
```